# Taking out of leading Zeros in the string (customer number input field)

Tags: php

I have one file custLogin.php. Currently I am taking the input as customer number in the login page. As I need to implement the 
below requirement:

1. Modify the customer number input field by accepting the MAX 12 digits numbers in custLogin page.
2. Combine the input customer number (i.e. 28907079) with the 12 zero numbers (i.e. 000000000000) to become a new set of the number (i.e. 00000000000028907079), 
   and then count the 9 digits from the right hand side and cut it down to become 9 digits number (028907079).

Snippet of the code:

In `custLogin.php`, this is the current code:

```
<div class="controls">
  <input type="text" name="customerNo" id="tep_customerNumber" value="<?php echo Filter::getInstance()->sanitize_var($showLoginFormCustNo)->asEncodedHtml()->value; ?>" class="input-block-level">
</div>
```

There is another file `Filter.php`:

```
public static function getInstance(){
    if(self::$instance === null)
    {
        self::$instance = new static();
    }
    self::$instance->value = null;
    return self::$instance;
}

public function sanitize_var($name, $default=null, $addScript = false){
    $this->value = isset($name) ? filter_var($name,FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW) : $default;
    $this->sanitize_default($addScript);
    return $this;
}
```

Can anyone guide me that how can I implement the above requirement in `PHP`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Dropdown list - adding leading zero's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277259/php-dropdown-list-adding-leading-zeros)

Comment: if ( [mb_strlen(...)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php)  <= 12) { ... } ?

Comment: But my query is taking out of leading zeros that is different from the link you specified.

Comment: Why add zeros to then take them out ? Just `str_pad` to required length as suggested. But if there's some weird requirement, use [`substr($customerNo, -9)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: As I am Adding of 12 leading zeros to customer number and then take out 9 digits from the right of customer number that would be consider as final customer number,  this is the requirement to implement in this way.

Comment: I think str_pad would not be working as length of final customer number is 9 that would be less than length of original string.

Comment: I would try with substr method. Thank you very much.